# Machine Learning: Simulated Annealing on Autoencoders

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, simulated-annealing, autoencoder

I have implemented simulated annealing for solving the cost function of a simple weight tying neural network, but am receiving some weird results.

Logic:

- Forward prop : f(W*x+b), where f = tanh, W = weight matrix, x = input data, b = bias
- Weights & bias are randomly initialized using rnd gaussian weights
- Weights & bias are normalized by W/norm2(W) & b/norm2(b)
- perturb W as: W +/- rnd_unif[0,1]  & do the same for b
- forward prop again, if the MSE < previous MSE accept, else use the annealing criterion
- Update temperature every n'th accept. Using generic T=T*0.9

What seems to be happening is that the network does reduce it's cost as expected, however some error predictions have an MSE lower than the 'normal' state MSE. In backprop we observe that the MSE is always higher for errors. I was wondering if someone else ran into the same problem.